# Get File create date with Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I want to get additional information about files using Java NIO. I use this Java code to get basic information:

```
private List<LogObj> generateFilesList()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        File[] files = new File("/ot").listFiles();

        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                LogObj obj = new LogObj(file.getName(), null, file.length());
                list.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

How I can get additional information about file create date?

Comment: Also voting "close as duplicate". Question says "using NIO" and is tagged with "nio", but does not explain that bit, so it does probably not actually matter to OP.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your code to this:

```
private List<LogObj> generateFilesList()
{
    List list = new ArrayList();
    File[] files = new File("/ot").listFiles();

    for (File file : files)
    {
        if (file.isFile())
        {
            LogObj obj = new LogObj(file.getName(), null, file.length());
            list.add(obj);
            BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(file.toURI()), BasicFileAttributes.class);
            FileTime fileTime = attributes.creationTime();
            Date date = new Date(fileTime.toMillis());
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you show me full example with Java NIO?

Comment: That is already full code.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the API description https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html

Comment: Can you paste here working example, please?

Comment: The working example can be found under the link that was posted by maytham